# remote gui support

Tags: linux, x11, gnome, remote-desktop

On Linux, is there any possible solution for remote GUI support?
It must work on gnome3.

Currently, I have X11VNC with gnome2 which runs as service. This has VNC sharing a user's physical desktop. Issue is I can run x11VNC on gnome3 but only under the specific user that is currently logged in, but I don't know which user will be logged in; I need to access the lock screen for full support.

x11VNC works with lightDM, but lockscreen stopped working and it looks like there are some other issues with lightdm and gnome.

Case scenario: LDAP user working on GUI and has an issue.  I would need to access this pc remotely; ssh is not enough because the issues are mostly with GUI applications.

Comment: Do you want to share the screen with a/the user that is logged in or have a completely separate GUI for the remote login?

Comment: share screen with activli logged user

Comment: Are there multiple users logged in at once or only one user with GUI access? You will have to explain your use case and setup in some more detail for a good answer.

Comment: one at time user ( but i can be any user from ldap) working in gui